# Accessing Query string in postback event while using URL rewrite 2.0 in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, url, iis-7, url-rewriting, query-string

I am in a trouble working with URL Rewrite 2.0 (in IIS7) for Web form web-app. In application there are job postings whose URL was not earlier SEO friendly and not in readable form as

***"http:www.mySite.com/candidate/JobDetails.aspx?ref=h_hj&JobPostingID=10049"***

I wrote Inbound Rule for that page i.e. for **JobDetails.aspx** as

**Pattern to match: `^candidate/JobDetails\.aspx$`**

**Conditions      : `{QUERY_STRING} and  pattern: ^ref=([^=&]+)&JobPostingID=([^=&]+)$`**

**Action          : `type: Rewrite and Rewrite URL: {C:1}/{C:2}`**

And it gave me new url string as

http://www.mySite.com/h_hj/10049

Now the problems are

1) I am unable to get query string values from URL as it is giving me problem during post back event as "Input string was not in a correct format."

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["JobPostingID"]))
            return Convert.ToUInt32(Request.QueryString["JobPostingID"]);
```

2) How to hide referral query string parameters only from URL as "ref" in my case.

Comment: you need to get those value with Route data

Answer (score 1):

Access your RouteData variable using [RouteData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata.aspx)and Also refer this link [Asp.net Routing](http://www.aspnet101.com/2010/04/asp-net-4-0-routing-tutorial/)

```
int JobPostID= Convert.ToInt32(Page.RouteData.Values["JobPostingID"]);
// do Some fun with your JobPostID
```

Comment: Hey Thanx, but I am using url rewriting not routing, I used things you said and its giving error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." as no value is assigning to it.